# Fiddler Session Object Documentation

Tags: fiddler

Where can I find any documentation on the properties and methods of the Fiddler.Session object? I am creating some custom rules (js) in Fiddler for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Script Editor and click View > Class Explorer. http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddlerscript-editor

Also check out the documentation (hit <kbd>F1</kbd>) and the book http://fiddlerbook.com

Comment: I know this is old but the documentation I get when I press F1 doesn't seem complete. For example, where's the Session object docs? Can't find them anywhere in those docs.

Comment: @FireCubez - The F1 documentation is quite limited indeed. The Fiddler book is much more comprehensive. But I think you'll also find the generated docs for FiddlerCore helpful; see https://fiddlerbook.com/om/html/419FBFCA.htm

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler shares a lot of code with [FiddlerCore](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore), so, for most cases, you can use [FiddlerCore API reference](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-core/api/), and more specifically the one for the [Session class](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-core/api/fiddler.session).