# How to add a column for the original size of the request?

Tags: fiddler

When an HTTP response is compressed, Fiddler will show you the size of the original body in the response, in the right window.

How can I add this information as a column in Fiddler's main view ?

[image: Screen capture of fiddler's HTTP response inspection window.]

Answer (score 0):

Generally Fiddler provides you several ways to **[Customize Columns](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Tasks/ConfigureColumns)**.

One way is using the QuickExec bar, i.e. using `cols add [Title] FlagName`, where `FlagName` can refer to a **[session flag](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/SessionFlags)** or request/response header if @ is used. Examples:

```
cols add @Request.Accept
cols add "Client IP Address" X-CLIENTIP
```

However, the information you're looking to add is not included in the response headers but it is rather **a calculated value**, thus the mentioned technique won't help you here.

Instead, what you can do is to use **[add the column using FiddlerScript](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/AddColumns)**.

To do that you'll have to edit the FiddlerScript (CTRL+R) and then add a method labeled with the **BindUIColumn** attribute, i.e.:

```
public static BindUIColumn("HTTPMethod") function CalcMethodCol(oS: Session) {
    // your custom logic for calculating and returning the uncompressed message body size 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any pointers to the documentation of classes Session and Request, so I can use those to calculate the uncompressed size ? I could not find them in the links you provided.

Comment: Check out **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017803/fiddler-session-object-documentation)** for Eric Lawrence's suggestions of how you can get this data (Eric Lawrence is the original Fiddler developer)